# Getting object member variable in one line of code from an array of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, oop, foreach, array-map

I am caught in a situation where I need to get values of a member variable of instances of an object which are in an array. Is there any way to use a function like array_map to get them in one line rather than using a foreach loop. Please see the code example below.

```
<?php

Class abc
{
   public $aVar;
   function __construct($Initialize)
   {
       $this->aVar = $Initialize;
   }
};

$Array = array(new abc(10), new abc(20), new abc(30));

$Array2 = array();

foreach ($Array as $Element)
{
    array_push($Array2, $Element->aVar);
}

print_r($Array2);
?>
```

Output is:

Array
(

[0] => 10

[1] => 20

[2] => 30

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
$newAray = array_map(function ($abcObj) {
    return $abcObj->aVar;
}, $Array);

print_r($newAray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 30
)
```

<s>Though, performance-wise, I'd guess this doesn't change much.</s>

**Edit**: Actually using `array_map` is far worse than `foreach`. Just a quick test with microtime and 1000000 iterations gave me:

```
foreach: 0.83289s
array_map: 2.95562s
```

on my test machine. So, I'd say, stick with the foreach.